# I can't run an instanceof the LocalDateTime in activity android Nougat 7.x,

Tags: java, android, android-7.0-nougat

I can't run an instanceof the **LocalDateTime** in activity **android Nougat 7.x**,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`LocalDateTime` was added to Android in API Level 26](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), otherwise known as Android 8.0. You cannot use it on older devices.